# Why "truly" instead of "truely"?

Tags: spelling

Is there any reason, historical or grammatical etc? Why isn't this tolerated like "judgement" or "blueish"?

I couldn't find related posts around here or EL&U forum as far as I searched. I'd truely appreciate your answers...

Comment: *Truely* is attested historically: http://internetshakespeare.uvic.ca/Annex/Texts/Ado/F1/default/ - http://viewer.soton.ac.uk/library/!fulltext/95111256/289/

Comment: Writers of the language hold a continually running election and *truly* has been since 17th century the consistent winner over *truely*, *truelye*, *trewly*, *trooly* and other also-rans.

Comment: Interesting, in the same folio it's spelled *truly*, i.e. 4.1. @snailboat. And elsewhere in Shakespeare it's got *truly*.

Comment: In American English, *judgment* is more tolerated. :) At least that's the [normal spelling](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/judgement). Not that I spell it that way--it looks weird without the *e* to me.

Comment: @pazzo i spell it that way precisely because it looks weird (because i think it's funny), and i also always prefer shorter words whenever possible. the extra e in *judgement* is just ... extra. because many others have agreed it's not needed, i have no problem omitting it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you mean  you *truly* appreciate our answers, because--like it or not--that is the modern spelling. You are free to differ from the norm.

I don't know the *why* (other than an arbitrary rule or practice, such as the one below from the OED), but the *how* is almost certainly due to dictionary standardization, or standardisation if you prefer the BrE spelling.

EDIT:

from the OED (which gives observations, not rules):

> ...
> When -ly is attached to a disyllabic or polysyllabic adj. in -le, the word is contracted, as in ably, doubly, singly, simply; contractions of this kind occur already in the 14th c., but examples of the uncontracted forms (e.g. doublely) are found as late as the 17th c.
>
> **Whole + -ly suffix2   becomes wholly, but in all other similar instances the written e is retained before the suffix, e.g. in palely, vilely, puerilely.**
>
> Adjs. ending graphically with ll lose one l before -ly, as in fully (in southern English commonly pronounced with a single l, but in Scotland often with double or long l), dully /ˈdʌllɪ/ , coolly /ˈkuːllɪ/ . Adjs. of more than one syll. ending in y change y to i before -ly, as in merrily; in formations from monosyllabic adjs. the usage varies, e.g. dryly, drily; gayly, gaily (cf. daily adj., which is the only current form); slyly, slily (but always shyly); greyly, grayly has always y. Another orthographical point is the dropping of the e in the two words duly, truly.
>
> **Another orthographical point is the dropping of the e in the two words duly, truly.**
>
> It is unusual to append -ly to an adj. in -ic; the ending of the adv. is nearly always -ically suffix, even when the only current form of the adj. ends in -ic.

Note the "rule" and then the exceptions, *duly* and *truly*--so there is no real reason other than this arbitrary practice, and these spellings became enshrined in a dictionary.

The influential 1755 [*A Dictionary of the English Language*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Dictionary_of_the_English_Language) by Samuel Johnson spells the word as *truly*. Here is the entry snipped from the [online version](https://archive.org/details/dictionaryofengl02johnuoft):

[image]

Corresponding to publiction in dictionary, there is no spelling of the word in the entry for *truly* in the *Oxford English Dictionary (OED)* that deviates from the spelling *truly* after about 1700. *Truly* existed before, along with variant spellings. (*Truely* exists in other entries after 1700.)

Another word, *blue*, whose modern adverbial form **bluely** exists from the late 16th century, was also spelled  *blewly* and *bluly* before about 1750.

And although we retain the *e* in **nicely** and **bluely**, we do not in **wholly** and **duly**--which are also how the 1755 dictionary spells the words. Frankly, these rules are arbitrary, and *wholely* and *duely* look about as good as *truely*.

Comment: "Duely" could get confused with "dually" (meaning "as a second function", or "a vehicle with pairs of wheels where most vehicles have single wheels"), or "duel" + "ly".  "Duly" also makes a nice visual pair with "duty", which has a similar meaning.

Answer (score 1):

English words [don't](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/english-words-dont-usually-end-with-u/) often end in *u* (there are exceptions as always!). The *e* in *true, cue, blue, due* etc., therefore serves the function of making the *u* word-medial. ⟨ue⟩ is a common spelling for [uː] (as in *tr**ue***) and [juː] (as in *d**ue***), so the *e* in 'true' and 'due' is there for making the *u* word-medial.

However, when we append *-ly* to 'true' and 'due', the *u* becomes medial and the *e* becomes superfluous. As is the case with [*argument* (not *argu**e**ment*)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/270389/106592). Although **truely* [is attested](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/truely), it's a misspelling now.

If you don't believe me, [look it up in  the *Irregularities in Modern English by W. Hansen and Hans Frede*](https://benjamins.com/catalog/nss.2)